# Can I travel in Switzerland/EU with a German Aufenthaltstitel (permanent residence permit)

Tags: usa, schengen, passports, eu, switzerland

I am a US citizen and permanent resident of Germany. I am in the process of becoming a German citizen. This requires me to renounce my US citizenship, but the US Consulate in Germany is extremely backed up. I have heard of people travelling to renounce citizenship, but my understanding is that I would give up my passport during the appointment. Since I have no other citizenship, I would then have to return to Germany with no passport at all. All I would have is my German residence permit (along with various paperwork that would explain my situation). Is it possible to travel this way?

Comment: This probably belongs on [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Germany requires a valid passport for entry into the territory, as laid out per [AufenthG § 3](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0043), a residence permit alone is not valid for entry.

> (1) Foreigners may enter or stay in the federal territory only if they possess a recognised and valid passport or passport substitute, unless they are exempt from the passport requirement by virtue of a statutory instrument. For the purpose of residence in the federal territory, possession of a substitute identity document also suffices in order to meet the passport requirement (section 48 (2)).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Charlie I don't think there are systematic controls on the border today.

Comment: @Charlie furthermore, [you will need a valid US passport to apply for naturalization](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/318998/).  You don't need to be stateless at the time of applying, only "prepared to give up your previous nationality" _(bereit, Ihre bisherige Staatsangehörigkeit aufzugeben)_.  You should also investigate the exceptions, in particular whether the $2,350 fee or the expatriation tax is an "unreasonable condition" or a "substantial disadvantage of a financial nature" (Nationality Act [StAG] section 12).

Comment: @Charlie in addition, you might consider that the US Immigration and Nationality Act provides that applying for naturalization in a foreign state with the intention of losing your US citizenship causes you automatically to lose US citizenship.  The executive branch would rather take the $2,350 fee for a renunciation, but it's not legally necessary.  You might have to go to court if you try that route, however.

Comment: @phoog But the last step you must actualy give up the other citizenship. A **Einbürgerungszusicherung** (intent to naturalize) is issued telling you that now is the time to do it.

Comment: Your assumption is **not** correct. You must supply proof that the other nationality has been renounced.

Comment: @MarkJohnson do you have a German government source describing this requirement, or the details of the administrative process? I couldn't find one.

Comment: Indeed, deleting this part

Comment: @phoog [§10(1)(4) Nationality Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stag/englisch_stag.html#p0063) ; (German only) [Verwaltungsvorschrift zum Staatsangehörigkeitsrecht](https://www.verwaltungsvorschriften-im-internet.de/bsvwvbund_13122000_V612400513.htm): 8.1.2.6.1 Einbürgerungszusicherung

Comment: @MarkJohnson yes, I saw that line in the statute, but I haven't seen any description of the process that specifies when the evidence of loss of previous nationality must be presented to German authorities.  In other words, a more detailed description of the administrative procedure would be helpful to people planning to naturalize as German.  If the German government does not provide such a description, some credible third-party source like an association supporting immigrants, or even a blog describing personal experience, would be helpful.

Comment: @phoog Why isn't this sentence (in the second link) sufficient? *Durch sie [Einbürgerungszusicherung] wird ihm die Einbürgerung für den Fall zugesagt, dass er die Aufgabe seiner Staatsangehörigkeit nachweist*. (It promises them naturalization in the event that they prove that they have given up their nationality.)

Comment: @MarkJohnson what's the source of the quotation concerning the Einbürgerungszusicherung?  The pages I've found do not mention the Einbürgerungszusicherung, do not describe how to get one, and do not describe what to do with it after renouncing one's other nationality.  If the source of your quotation does these things, it would be sufficient.

Comment: @phoog The source is the second link. Look for **8.1.2.6.1 Einbürgerungszusicherung**, second sentance

Answer (score 0):

Once you renounce your US citizenship, you will be considered (for the German authorities at least) to be **stateless** and will no longer have a US passport to travel with.

This normally must be done **outside** the US, so I assume you wish to do this from within the Schengen Area to avoid any regular passport control.

The German **Einbürgerungszusicherung** will probably be required by the US officials (outside of Germany it may have to be translated).

This, togeather with a letter confirming that your passport has been retained would explain the reason why you are returning to Germany without a required travel document. Because of this, if you are actualy found out, it would probably have no further consequences.

This letter would also be usefull when applying for a stateless passport (see below).

Part of the process is that a [Certificate of Loss of Nationality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_of_Loss_of_Nationality) will be issued immediately, **but** will first be sent to the State Department for 'review' and later sent back to you.

Even before **FATCA** this could have taken quite some time (early 1980's 6 months).

The confirmed **Certificate of Loss of Nationality** is what the German authorities require to complete the naturalization process.

During this time you are eligible for a **stateless** passport that will be issued by the local immigration office (see link for Berlin below).

With this travel document, togeather with your residence permit card, you can travel to other countries.

---

- [Travel document - Reissue - Services - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/325471/en/)

  > - [Prado: Fremdenpass (Blau) 2017](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/DEU-JO-04001/index.html)
  >
  > [image]

Comment: "The German Einbürgerungszusicherung will probably be required by the US officials": the US doesn't care about this.  "a Certificate of Loss of Nationality will be issued immediately, but will first be sent to the State Department for 'review' and later sent back to you": this isn't a particularly accurate description of [the actual procedure](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/07FAM/07FAM1210.html).  Also, the US won't issue a US visa to the person while the certificate is pending; they treat the person as a US citizen until it is actually issued to the person.

Comment: @phoog That was how it was done in the past, where a friend of mine when through the process and how the US Embassy and Consulate in the Netherlands says it being done today. [Request an Appointment - U.S. Embassy and Consulate in the Netherlands](https://nl.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/citizenship-services/renunciation-u-s-citizenship/request-an-appointment/): *After the interview your application **will be forwarded to the Department of State for review**. This process may take several months to complete*.

Comment: @phoog Actually, your source confirms this: **Who may approve a Certificate of Loss of Nationality**:  *...  This is one area of citizenship and nationality law that has not been delegated to U.S. consular officers abroad and, absent a change in the statute, cannot be delegated to post. (1)  Generally a division chief in the Office of American Citizen Services and Crisis Management (CA/OCS/ACS) in the Directorate of Overseas Citizens Services, Bureau of Consular Affairs of the Department of State, reviews and approves a Certificate of Loss of Nationality (CLN);*

Comment: Forwarding an application for review is not the same as issuing a certificate immediately and forwarding the certificate for review.  There is nothing in that source that suggests that the consular officer issues a certificate before the review, and indeed handling the process that way would make little sense.

Comment: @phoog Oh, please - be realistic. Look at the wiki link where a photo can be seen. It is signed and sealed by the consulate official on one date and approved 80 days later. The only difference to the 1980 one (a copy of which I have) that it was stamped/approved in Wash. D.C. and sent per post from there. Sidenote: in 1980 it was free of charge.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that the person named on the certificate [had it in his own possession during the 15 months (not 80 days) that it took for the US government to approve it](https://glr.com/19252/Certificate_of_Loss_of_Nationality_CLN_Glen_L_Roberts_Earthling_Stateless). But the officer who completed the certificate didn't fill it out correctly, so it would be no surprise if he failed to follow protocol in other respects.  A person whose CLN has not yet been approved [is still treated as a US citizen for travel to the US](https://fam.state.gov/fam/07fam/07fam1220.html#M1224).

Comment: @phoog And does this help the OP **in any way, shape or form** when travelling between Schengen States (and thus relevant to this question)?

Comment: Yes it does.  It means that he should still have his US passport after applying for renunciation, since it won't be cancelled until months later when the application is approved, so he'll be able to return to Germany with the US passport in hand.

Comment: @phoog Your source says otherwise: **7 FAM 1227 (e)(2)**: *The post should take possession of any and all valid (unexpired) U.S. passport book(s) and passport card(s) of the individual when the individual executes either Form DS-4080, Oath of Renunciation of the Nationality...* It also justifies the issuing of a travel document by a 3rd country as a stateless person, since the **Oath of Renunciation** has been made but not yet approved.

Comment: @phoog The protocol seems to be that the individuals copy should only be sent after the approval. [7 FAM 1268 CHECKLIST (4)(e)](https://fam.state.gov/fam/07fam/07fam1260.html#M1268): *If the CLN is approved, put the official stamp attesting to departmental approval **on the two original** CLNs, **and provide one original paper copy of the CLN package to the individual by registered mail**.*